# How do I set up healthprobe for a web application running on an Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring, azure-load-balancer

State of the application:

- A single virtual machine which runs an apache server.
- Application exposed via the virtual machine's public IP (not behind a loadbalancer)

I have an healthprobe endpoint running that needs probed every few seconds to see if the app is up, and trigger an alert in case it is not.

What are my options? I want to get the healthprobe up and running first, before I move to a virtual machine scale set and a load balancer.

Comment: Is the endpoint a public accessible http(s) endpoint?

Comment: @PeterBons Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a watchdog that calls the health endpoint at a given interval. In Azure you can use an [availability test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability). You can then [create alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-alerts) based on this availability and optionally create dashboards that show the status over a given period.

As a bonus you might integrate the application insights resource in your web app to get detailed monitoring. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)

Comment: Thank you! Azure app insights and seems like a great place for me to start. The availability test and alerting suits my immediate use case very well.

Answer (score 0):

Under **Support+troubleshooting -> Resource health** of your virtual machine portal panel, you can set up a health alert.
You can then select under which conditions the alert should be triggered. In your case, **Current resource status: Unavailable** should work just fine. You can also implement a custom notification (E-Mail) under Actions or implement a logic that triggers an Azure Function or Logic App that performs an action when the VM is unavailable.

To detect if your application in Apache server is working correctly you can use a monitoring solution that checks the Apache error logs.

Comment: What if the VM is running just fine but the workload isn't?

Comment: You're right Peter. Thanks for pointing it out.